# Installed packages can't be imported in code while non-installed packages can be

Tags: python, import, module, package

I have a weird issue. I have used the terminal in Visual Studio Code to install a package using `pip`. However, in my code, when I use `import`, I get a `ModuleNotFoundError`.

On the other hand, there are packages like `SymPy` that I can successfully `import` in my code. But in the terminal, when I type `pip show sympy` I get the output `WARNING: Package(s) not found: sympy`. What is wrong with my Python setup?

Moreover, I used the Windows command prompt and typed `where python` and the location of the `python.exe` file was displayed. But in Visual Studio Code, pressing `Ctrl+Shift+P` to open the Command Pallette and typing `Python: Select Interpreter`, I get a list of interpreters. However, the location which was displayed by the Windows command prompt is not displayed here. I have an option to manually enter the Interpreter path. I tried that but get an error saying that `The file cannot be accessed by the system`.

How do I fix this?